# How do I determine the coordinates tapped on AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

- I have a CACaptureVideoPreviewLayer that spans the entire width and height of my app's view.
- I have AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill enabled on my preview layer.
- The user eventually taps the preview layer. I am provided with the CGPoint of where the user has tapped the layer in my view's coordinates.

How do I get the pixel that was tapped on the CACaptureVideoPreviewLayer in terms of the camera's output coordinates?